# How to import a CSS file for a package in react.js during bootstrapping?

Tags: css, reactjs, import

I'm using a spreadsheet package called [React-Datasheet](https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet#react-datasheet) installed with npm in my react.js project. The following instructions are found in the GitHub:

```
import ReactDataSheet from 'react-datasheet';
// Be sure to include styles at some point, probably during your bootstrapping
import 'react-datasheet/lib/react-datasheet.css';
```

When I compile the code the styling file does not compile with it. What is the method used to add the react-datasheet.css file?

The content currently renders like this:

[image]

How do I import the css file to result in a render that looks like this:

[image: react]

Comment: try adding `style-loader`  https://www.npmjs.com/package/style-loader

Comment: I've tried adding style loader and css loader to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add this css in your index as what I found is it has further css
https://github.com/nadbm/react-datasheet/blob/master/docs/src/index.css

and add <div className={"sheet-container"}> class or div before rendering ReactDataSheet